# How to trim all strings from a complex object returned with dapper

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dapper

I am working with a legacy database, within this database, the data get assigned the maximum length of the column. if the string data is shorter, it will automaticly fill in whitespaces at the end.

What i'm trying to do is trim all these ending whitespaces with every query i do.

i figured one of the better ways would be making an extension method for dapper query using reflection.

But i can't seem to get it to work.

parent entity:

```
public class Person: BaseEntity
   {
       public Identification Identification { get; set; }
       public Address Address { get; set; }
       public Contact Contact { get; set; }
       public Family Family { get; set; }
       public ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
   }
```

example of child entity:

```
 public class Address: BaseEntity
    {
        public string Street { get; set;  }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string BoxNumber { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i do my join query like this:

```
var result = _db.QueryTrim<dynamic>(sql, new { userid = id })
                .Select(p => new Person()
                {
Identification = IdentificationMapper.MapToIdentificationEntity(p),
                    Address = AddressMapper.MapToAddressEntity(p)}).First();
```

i am trying to implement something like this but i can't get it to work with query

```
public static class DapperExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) {
        var dapperResult = SqlMapper.Query<T>(cnn, sql, param, transaction, buffered, commandTimeout, commandType);
        var result = TrimStrings(dapperResult.ToList());
        return result;
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> TrimStrings<T>(IList<T> objects) {
        //todo: create an Attribute that can designate that a property shouldn't be trimmed if we need it
        var publicInstanceStringProperties = typeof (T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof (string) && x.CanRead &&  x.CanWrite);
        foreach (var prop in publicInstanceStringProperties) {
            foreach (var obj in objects) {
                var value = (string) prop.GetValue(obj);
                var trimmedValue = value.SafeTrim();
                prop.SetValue(obj, trimmedValue);
            }
        }
        return objects;
    }

    static string SafeTrim(this string source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return source.Trim();
    }
}
```

In the end i want to trim all string that come out of the database. At the moment i'm tunnelvisioning on the dapperextension, but if there is any better way. Please let me know.

Comment: Do it in the SQL?

Comment: @DavidG The problem is that i don't know beforehand which columns need trimming and which don't

Comment: How can you not know beforehand? Surely you know which columns are to be trimmed?

Comment: mhm maybe you are right. I'll try and implement it that way. In meantime i'll try out with a dapper extension, so i don't always have to write the RTRIM in the query

Comment: I second @DavidG. That's would also reduce the amount of data being transfered from the database.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Dapper version 1.50.2 you can do it in a simpler way.

Create a TypeHandler like the one bellow:

```cs
public class TrimmedStringHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<string>
{
    public override string Parse(object value)
    {
        string result = (value as string)?.Trim();
        return result;
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, string value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}
```

On the program initialization you must call the AddTypeHandler method of the SqlMapper class like bellow:

```cs
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new TrimmedStringHandler());
```

If you do this, every string that come from database will be trimmed.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It seems much easier to implement too.

Comment: Beautiful solution!  Works perfectly.